# CkEditor5 upcast of elementToStructure downcast

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor5

Like in the [documentation here](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/deep-dive/conversion/helpers/downcast.html#handling-model-elements-children) i want to use elementToStructure for an element in my model which itself has model-children.

in example:

```
conversion.for('dataDowncast').elementToStructure({
  model: 'titleRow',
  view: ( modelElement, conversionApi ) => {
    const { writer } = conversionApi;
    const triggerElement = writer.createContainerElement( 'button', { class: 'trigger-element'}, [
        writer.createSlot()
    ]);
    return writer.createContainerElement( 'h3', { class: 'title-element' }, [
        triggerElement
    ]);
  }
});
```

which works as desired and results in following structure:

```
<h3 class="title-element">
  <button class="trigger-element">
      <children_elements_from_model>
  </button>
</h3>
```

However i cannot find a way to do the upcasting from the structure again

i tries similiar things to

```
conversion.for('upcast').elementToElement({
  model: 'titleRow',
  view: {
    key: 'class',
    value: 'title-element',
  },
});
```

which will create my titleRow element in view but it does not parse/consume the children elements?  What would be the correct approach here?

There seems to be an issue on its github [elementToStructure() needs an equivalent structureToElement](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/11150) But it has been auto-closed due to inactivity